# Selectively copy go struct fields

Tags: go

I wanted a way to **selectively** copy Go fields from one struct to another. This allows me to *update* data from one struct to another without changing certain information. Here's the solution I came up with. It depends on setting a tag field of "update". Would appreciate any feedback for making this more robust or better or maybe why this is just a bad idea to begin with.

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func UpdateStruct(src, dst interface{}) error {
    if reflect.TypeOf(src) != reflect.TypeOf(dst) {
        return errors.New("structs not of same type")
    }

    if reflect.ValueOf(src).Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return errors.New("arguments must be pointers")
    }

    srcVal := reflect.ValueOf(src).Elem()
    srcType := srcVal.Type()

    dstVal := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < srcVal.NumField(); i++ {
        s := srcType.Field(i)
        if tag := s.Tag.Get("update"); tag == "" {
            continue
        }
        fieldName := srcType.Field(i).Name
        d := dstVal.FieldByName(fieldName)
        if d.IsValid() {
            if d.CanSet() {
                d.Set(srcVal.Field(i))
            } else {
                return fmt.Errorf("cannot set field: %s", fieldName)
            }
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("invalid field: %s", fieldName)
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

example struct:

```
type Tester struct {
    ID      string
    Name    string    `update:"true"`
    Date    time.Time `update:"true"`
    Decimal float64   `update:"true"`
    Number  int       `update:"true"`
    CaseID  uuid.UUID `update:"true"`
}
```

Comment: This implementation, is also supposed to work when there are structs within structs correct? it fails there. There is  a way of doing this using https://github.com/fatih/structs.

Comment: @whitespace OP's code works with the type in question and this type has nested structs.

Comment: @ThunderCat, I think you misunderstood my concern. I am not talking about first level copy. I think, question is still valid for structs which have structs inside them, where the nested structs have some fields I would want to copy and some fields I don't want to copy.

Comment: @whitespace The OP may want to selectively copy within nested structs, but the question does not ask for that feature, nor is that feature needed in all possible uses of the function.  Sebastian, do you want to selectively copy within nested structs or do you want to copy nested selects wholesale?

Comment: @whitespace selectively copying fields within nested structs is beyond the scope of my original question. Maybe someone will have that question down the road however. It could add to the robustness of this code or be part of another question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question so much as a request for code review, which belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

The code will panic if the arguments are not pointers to structs. There'a check for a pointer, but not for a pointer to a struct.  Add this code:

```
srcVal := reflect.ValueOf(src).Elem()
if srcVal.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    return errors.New("arguments must be pointers to structs")
}
```

Because the function is starting with a pointer to a struct, the fields are guaranteed to be settable. Because the field values are obtained from a valid struct value, the fields are guaranteed to be valid. Fields can be accessed by index in addition to by name.  Given this, the inner loop can be simplified to:

```
for i := 0; i < srcVal.NumField(); i++ {
    s := srcType.Field(i)
    if tag := s.Tag.Get("update"); tag == "" {
        continue
    }
    dstVal.Field(i).Set(srcVal.Field(i))
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JNBJrBBlHxQ)